# Does order matter when opening input and output files?

Tags: python, file

Is there a correct order when writing/reading a file?  This is what I normally do:

1. open "write" file
2. open "read" file
3. iterate through "read"
4. write to "write" file

```
with open(path + 'write_file.txt', 'wb') as txtout:
    with open(path + 'read_file.txt', 'rb') as txtin:
        for line in txtin:
            txtout.writelines(line)
```

Is there any reason to open the input file first? rather than open the output file first?

Comment: You may find answers over at [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

1) Open the input file first, then the output file. That way, if the input file doesn't exist, you can report that error without having first created the (now useless) output file.

2) Iterate over the input file (as you are doing), rather than calling `file.read()` or `file.readlines()`. Calling one of those functions can use an essentially unlimited amount of memory.

3) In the particular case you've given, use [`shutils.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) or [`shutils.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile).

Comment: 1 - is not correct. You will always get an error if your read file doesn't exist. Open it before or after.

Comment: That's not the point. Checking for the input file first saves you from doing cleanup in the case where your input doesn't exist.

Comment: @hagubear - I've rewritten the first point. Hopefully that explains the logic better.

Comment: is there a specific reason as to why you would make a copy of the input file vs iterating over it? for the example above, i iterate through the input file in order to extract data from it and create an output file. is there an advantage to copying the input file? btw, i started to open the input file first on my programs now, but i do however always check that the file exists with an if statement prior to running the program..

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of that:

```
with open("file_write", 'w') as f1, open("file_read") as f2:
      # bla bla bla
```

Or this:

```
with open("file_read") as f1, open("file_write", 'w') as f2:
```

Makes no difference. That's of course if your input file actually exists. With the 'w' flag, the file will be created/overwritten in case it doesn't exist. But the file object for `read` operation will return as "False" i.e. doesn't exist. As a matter of fact,it will generate error as soon as you want to access the read file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first read the file. There would be an error if the file doesn't exist and the operation for write would not start.